# grails spring bean definition

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

In my Grails plugin I define the following Spring beans

```
def doWithSpring = {

    // define a bean of type ConfigObjectHelper
    configHelper(ConfigObjectHelper)

    // Call a method of the bean we've just defined
    String appName = configHelper.getAsString('ftp.general.appName')

    // define another bean and pass appName to it's constructor
    pkApplication(Application, appName)
}
```

When I call `configHelper.getAsString` I get a NullPointerException, because `configHelper` does not refer to the bean I created in the previous line. Instead Grails looks for a property/field of the current class with this name. As none exists, I get a NullPointerException.

Is there a way to get a reference to a Spring bean within the `doWithSpring` closure?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do pkApplication.appName = configHelper.getAsString(...) in doWithApplicationContext closure? At that stage all beans defined in doWithSpring are instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

MethodInvokingFactoryBean to the rescue!

```
def doWithSpring = {

    // define a bean of type ConfigObjectHelper
    configHelper(ConfigObjectHelper)    

    appName(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean) {
        targetObject = ref('configHelper')
        targetMethod = 'getAsString'
        arguments = ['ftp.general.appName']
    }               

    // define another bean and pass appName to it's constructor
    pkApplication(Application, appName)
}
```